# Perform incremental deployment to Angular / Ionic projects?

Tags: angular, ionic4

Since Angular 2, and Ionic 2, the build output now bundles all HTML files, CSS file and JS/TS files into what they call Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compilation.

This is good and all except it is very hard to deploy small changes or deploy them incremental changes.

For example, I found a spelling mistake in one the pages and I need to correct it; in AngularJS, I can deploy just the modified the HTML template file to production and be done.

Now in AOT compilation (esp. for apps with Ionic framework), I now need to rebuild and redeploy the whole project of tens (sometimes hundreds) of MB of files which doesn't make sense.

Is there any way to compile and produce only the incremental changes using angular CLI build and deploy them?

Or am I dreaming?

Cheers